# Is INT in struct tab need to be malloc?

Tags: c, variables, pointers, structure

I've the following code :

```
int parser_start(t_control *shell)
{
  int   i;
  int   c;
  int   count;
  int   separator;

  count = 0;
  shell->command_index = 1;
  shell->commands = malloc(parser_count_separators(shell));
  shell->commands[count] = malloc(sizeof(shell->commands));
  shell->commands[count]->command = malloc(my_strlen(shell->cli) * sizeof(char));
  shell->commands[count]->op = 0;
  i = 0;
  c = 0;
  while (shell->cli[i] != '\0')
    {
      separator = parser_is_separator(shell->cli[i], shell->cli[i + 1]);
      if (separator == -1)
    shell->commands[count]->command[c++] = shell->cli[i];
      else
    {
      shell->command_index++;
      count++;
      shell->commands[count] = malloc(sizeof(shell->commands));
      shell->commands[count]->command = malloc(my_strlen(shell->cli) * sizeof(char));
      shell->commands[count]->op = separator;
      my_printf("%d\n", shell->commands[count]->op);
      c = 0;
    }
      i = i + parser_separator_get_size(separator);
    }
}
```

With the following struct :

```
typedef struct s_command
{
  char  *command;
  char  *program;
  char  **argv;
  int   argc;
  pid_t pid;
  int   op;
} t_command;

typedef struct s_control
{
  pid_t pid;
  char  **env;
  char  **path;
  char  *cli;
  int   fd_history;
  int   power;
  int   pipefd[2];
  int   command_index;
  char  **builtins;
  int   (*builtins_fptr[6])(struct s_control *, int );
  t_command **commands;
} t_control;
```

When I dump `shell->commands[count]->op` with my `printf`, it print `1` as I want.

When I dump the same emplacement in another function I got `7564320`.
Why ? Does my `op` field needs to be malloc too?

Thanks

Comment: You didn't include the very inportant `struct` definitions, also you assume that `malloc()` always returns a valid pointer, that is wrong and hence dangerous, you need to post the `struct` definitions. Also, _When I dump the same emplacement in another function I got `7564320`_, what you mean there is not clear, the code is also required, and the answer is no, you don't need to `malloc()` an `int`, as to why it is failing, the code where you get the `7564320` is needed.

Comment: I've a added the struct definition.

Answer (score 0):

While it is hard to tell without seeing more code, the most likely culprit is:

```
shell->commands = malloc(parser_count_separators(shell));
```

It's clear that the `commands` field of the `t_control` structure is a pointer. Without seeing the code for `parser_count_separators`, it is hard to know for certain, but it seems reasonable that `parser_count_separators(shell)` will return a count of separators, and that the *size* of `commands` should be either

```
parser_count_separators(shell) * sizeof *shell->commands)
```

or

```
(parser_count_separators(shell) + 1) * sizeof *shell->commands)
```

depending on whether `parser_count_separators` actually counts *separators* as its name implies, or counts *subcommands* (which is one more than the number of separators).

Comment: It seems reasonable that this can be the cause, but it's really a blind guess, isn't it?

Comment: @iharob: not entirely blind. I'm guided by my crystal ball. :)

Comment: No it can't come from this because the other field of the structs are correctly set (like strings and pid). The INT is the only problem

Comment: @Teldar: The fact that you use unallocated memory does not *guarantee* that you will encounter a problem immediately (or ever). Not every byte of the unallocated memory is necessarily modified by the time you printf the values.

Comment: @Teldar are you on linux? if so, use [valgrind](http://www.valgrind.org), and check that you are not doing any illegal writes, because it seems to me that this is the problem, but the context in your question doesn't let the reader know how did you reach the erroneous result.

Comment: @rici and please can I borrow your crystal ball? I wish it was possible to use such a debugger.